# Copy Trello card and change information with data from google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, trello

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheet with 2 information:
Name and Description
How do I copy an "existing card" and update only these two information based on the worksheet.
Detail I have over 1000 rows in the worksheet.

Visit [a link] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ORhZzD5WI0zcrTtNikixXXA9Dd_sknv8NtEnfqK97E/edit#gid=0

I've tried using integromat but it's a paid tool.

```
import gmail_app
import google_sheets_app
import trello_app

## STEP 1: SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE SHEETS IN THE SIDEBAR
## STEP 2: PASTE A GOOGLE SHEET'S ID BELOW (FOUND IN ITS URL)
sheet_id = "12ORhZzD5WI0zcrTtNikixXXA9Dd_sknv8NtEnfqK97E"


def export_to_sheets():
    # get all open cards in this board
    board = trello_app.get_current_board()
    cards = board.get_cards(filter="open")

    # export cards to the google sheet
    sheet = google_sheets_app.get_spreadsheet_by_id(sheet_id).get_sheets()[0]
    sheet.write_values(cards)


def import_from_sheets():
    # read the google sheet
    sheet = google_sheets_app.get_spreadsheet_by_id(sheet_id).get_sheets()[0]
    sheet_data = sheet.get_values()

    # for each row in sheet
    for row in sheet_data:
        # look for an ID column, and lookup that card
        card = trello_app.get_card_by_id(row.get("id"))

        # if you find a card, update it with the row
        if card:
            card.set_field(row)
        # if this card doesn't exist, create it
        else:
            li = trello_app.get_list_by_id(row.get("idList"))
            li.create_card(row)

    # when done, pull updated card list into sheets
    export_to_sheets()
```

Comment: Is the question "How to do what I was doing in integromat, but with free tools?", or is it "How do I find the right row to update?", or is it "how do it add just the fields I'm interested in to the sheet?"  ?

Comment: Thank you   @ShapeOfMatter
I want to copy an existing card and update the data based on the google sheets.

Trello example images:
[link] 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J-BGc_yBgVJEQ3wnt9-vQl4PvG_AwON/view?usp=sharing
[link]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VTuJXjp1B-7gOvqb_B45z0dttD3AyV0B/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J-BGc_yBgVJEQ3wnt9-AvQl4PvG_AwON/view